# mixing gridlayout and borderlayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, border-layout

I was tired but before quitting just stuck in the nearly-last 3 lines in the code snippet below to make a "refresh" button on my tictactoe panel, hoping to get away with it but expecting errors, since it mixes layout managers on a single container.

But it WORKED.

```
ButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));    
guiFrame.add(ButtonPanel); 
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    button[i][j] = addButton(ButtonPanel, i, j);
  }
}

JButton refreshbutton = new JButton("Refresh");
guiFrame.add(refreshbutton, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // ... border layout worked. Hm.
refreshbutton.addActionListener(this);

guiFrame.setVisible(true);   }
```

Should I be surprised? (Keep in mind my newbieness.)

(*BOY*, did I learn/stumble onto a buncha stuff in writing this silly game's program!!!--for instance, using `setActionCommand` to "label" each button internally [as 11,12,13,21,...33] so the ONE `actionPerformed` method could use `getActionCommand` to correctly label [with X or O] whatever button was pushed by whoever's turn it was.)

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. `ButtonPanel` should be `buttonPanel`.

Comment: Moreover, please in future refer `BorderLayout.SOUTH` with `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`, since the latter is preferred over the former  since JDK 1.4 :-) More information can be found on [BorderLayout Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), just below the __Launch Button :-)__ Moreover, you failed to call `guiFrame.pack()` just before setting it to visible and after adding all components to it, which is quite a common mistake all newbies do, when coding in Swing, which leads to obnoxious behaviour in many cases __(HARD TO TELL IN THIS SMALL SPACE)__ :-)

Answer (score 2):

> guiFrame.add(refreshbutton, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // ... border layout worked. Hm.

Just because you used BorderLayout.SOUTH does not make a panel a BorderLayout. Your code worked because the default layout manager for the content pane of a JFrame (JDialog) is a BorderLayout. So you are just taking advantage of the default layout.

> since it mixes layout managers on a single container.

Yes, this is a common practice. In fact it is almost impossible to create a reasonably complex GUI if you don't use different layout managers on different panels that you add to a GUI.

Comment: Saw "pack()" in Netbeans-generated code; hadn't read about it; will add.

Comment: I just added pack() and now the tictactoe grid is minuscule, since I guess that's what pack() does. I guess now I have to mess with preferred size and whatnot but I'm just gonna remove pack for now until something better comes up either through reading or y'all.--I just read about setMinimumSize, but I don't know what a Dimension is.......

Comment: OK. Added these two lines:
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(300, 300);
    guiFrame.setMinimumSize(dim);
SO all is well. Thanks for makin' me learn about pack() and Dimension against my will!

Comment: Dropdown list for BorderLayout doesn't advise that SOUTH has been deprecated, but I changed it to PAGE_END.

Comment: I just replaced << guiFrame.setSize(300, 300); >> with 
<< guiFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300)); >> although I'm not sure .setSize should be avoided entirely; however, if using pack() is a "must", what's the point in using .setSize?